# VSCode Mac debugging little issue

Tags: python, debugging, visual-studio-code

https://i.stack.imgur.com/k0Ypt.png
Hi guys!

I wanted to come back to the coding world and been practicing with VSCode on Mac. Since today, I don't know what I have done that every time that I debug Python code it shows me the image abobe. It's not a big issue but for me, it is very annoying since I like to keep things clean and simple.

I tried to uninstall every extension and add-on on VS and uninstall but I can solve it myself.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the command to execute the debugger, so there's not much you can do about it without changing your `launch.json` to not use the terminal.

Comment: More specifically, add `"console": "none",` to `launch.json`

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of trying there's no solution. It's just how VScode works on Mac.